# Query result using geoflutterfire from firestore database using an flutter app returning null or nothing but there is no error in syntax

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

> Here lattitude and longitude to the function are my current location and are checked valid and proper imports are already used based on different functionality !

Stateful class and other ui and method implementation are there , just showing the bit having problem .

The stream.listen returns no documentList but with nothing inside , please help find the problem soon if possible .

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:burglar_alert/pages/drawerPage.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

import 'package:geoflutterfire/geoflutterfire.dart';



// classwise variable
  final geo = Geoflutterfire();
  final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

_getNearbyPeoples(lattitude, longitude) {
    GeoFirePoint center = geo.point(latitude: lattitude, longitude: longitude);
    var collectionReference = _firestore.collection('users');

    double radius = 50.0;
    String field = 'location';

    Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> stream = geo
        .collection(collectionRef: collectionReference)
        .within(center: center, radius: radius, field: field, strictMode: true);

    stream.listen((List<DocumentSnapshot?> documentList) {
      print("Printing DocumentList Data:");
      print(documentList[0]!.data());
    });
  }
```

[showing ui and on "help me" button click , result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBGVM.png)

[firestore databse structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSOuc.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you check the documentation for the `geoflutterfire` library on [writing geo data](https://pub.dev/packages/geoflutterfire#writing-geo-data), you'll see that it adds a field called `geohash` to the document. This is necessary in order to perform geoqueries on Firestore.

This `geohash` field is missing from the document in your screenshot, which means it will not be found by geoqueries.

To learn more about what this property is, and why it is needed, have a look at the Firebase documentation on [adding geoqueries to Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries) (it doesn't use the same library as you do, but the approach is the same) and the video from a talk I did a few years ago on [adding geoqueries to Firestore](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mx1mMdHBi5Q).